# Read a variable from PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I need to read a value of a config file and save it to a variable and then print to the screen. When I executed the below script I get an empty string for `$value` printed on the console.

```
$appContent = GET-CONTENT C:\content.config
$value = $appContent.Countries.add
Write-Host $value
```

**Content of C:\content.config  file**

```
<Countries>
    <add name="Serbia"  />
</Countries>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
[xml]$appContent = Get-Content C:\content.config
$appContent.Countries.add.Name
```